# Arcgis SceneLayer Editing - 3D

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am beginner in Arcgis 3D client side (JS) development.

I have a sceneLayer (a trial version from arcgis market place) and I have arcgis organisational account.

I created a app using webapp builder and the sceneLayer.

I just wanted to know,

is it possible to edit a feature in sceneLayer using arcgis javascript api like featurelayer.applyedit() ?

Answer (score 1):

No, SceneLayers do not have an applyedit() method

Comment: So it means, There is no edit functionality to edit the scenelayer from the client side (through arcgis javascript api). right ?

Comment: Correct, I don't think you can even edit FeatureLayers in a SceneView.

Answer (score 0):

The API has evolved a lot since the question was posted initially. Today:

- features in FeatureLayers can be edited using FeatureLayer.applyeEdits
- 3D Object SceneLayers can be edited as well using SceneLayer.applyEdits. This is part of the new SceneLayer editing capabilities: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-SceneLayer.html#applyEdits
- For both, the editor widget can be used to quickly build 3d apps with editing capabilities for FeatureLayers and SceneLayers https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-editor-3d/